cy.get with a specific class does not work for me
I want to click on a button that has the following
class: gameStart_wrapper__3lViH 

therefore I'm using
cy.get('.gameStart_wrapper__3lViH').click() 


and I also tried
cy.get('button[class*="gameStart_wrapper__3lViH "]').click(),

But it keeps showing me the error Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element but never found it.
What am I doing wrong? is it something I didn't set right before?
UPDATE
I realized that the class is inside an inframe
<iframe src="https://arenacloud.cdn.arkadiumhosted.com/arkadiummodulesstorage-blob/game-rendering-iframe/0.1.78/iframe-rendering-grm.html?gameId=&amp;env=prod" aria-label="canvas box for game" id="canvas-box" class="game Game_canvasBox__c050826e game Game__canvasBox___CSxfNXEh" allow="clipboard-read *; clipboard-write *;"></iframe>

So my new code is:

Cypress.Commands.add('getIframe', (iframeSelector) => {
  return cy.get(iframeSelector)
    .its('0.contentDocument').should('exist')
    .then(cy.wrap);
});

describe('Arkadium Crossword', () => {
  it('Start the game', () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.gamelab.com/games/daily-quick-crossword');
  });

  it('Navigate to a specific day within the game', () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.gamelab.com/games/daily-quick-crossword');

    
    cy.get('#canvas-box', { timeout: 10000 }).should('be.visible');

   
    cy.getIframe('#canvas-box').then((iframeBody) => {
      cy.wrap(iframeBody)
        .find('.gameStart_wrapper__3lViH', { timeout: 10000 })
        .as('gameStartButton')
        .should('be.visible')
        .then((button) => {
          
          try {
            cy.wrap(button).click();
            cy.log('Botão clicado com sucesso!');
          } catch (error) {
            cy.log('Erro ao clicar no botão:', error);
          }
        })
    })
  })
})

But it still says that the class cannot be found. What is happening?
enter image description here
enter image description here
